# Can there ever be a smallest unit of matter? Surely quarks and electrons must be made of something?

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics

Or is physics just being counter-intuitive again?

Comment: What's counter-intuitive about something being elementary? (i.e., indivisible)

Comment: Its turtles all the way down...

Comment: Strings are supposed to be way smaller. The corresponding length of a string is assumed to be on the order of Planck length. But there is no experimental evidence for string theory (yet).

Comment: @Arthur As elementary particles are considered to be pointlike, that doesn't seem smaller.

Comment: "Matter", of which you think, as some "solid substance", does not exist in nature. Only energy and fields of probability. In everyday life, we see a solid matter, but at the microscopic level it consists of many particles, which are not "solid".

Comment: As a general rule, the word "surely" does not count as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Like your other question regarding the size of particles, we don't know. With particles, we can't generate enough energy to probe to very, very small distances, and whatever particles are "made of", (if anything), it is nothing that you would see in the macro world.

Physics is really concerned with the properties of particles, rather than their composition. Even saying they are composed of strings, means you will (correctly, imo), post another question "what are strings made of" :)